# How can I tell JPA to use prepared statements (or dynamic sql)?

Tags: jpa, jdbc, openjpa

I do understand the advantages of prepared statments over dynamic sql as described in [Difference between Statement and PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271249/difference-between-statement-and-preparedstatement).

However I'm not sure how to tell JPA to (not) use a prepared statement.

I have a number of named queries. Is JPA automatically using prepared statments for this? What about criteria API. My guess is that it's using dynamic sql?

Comment: Where is your evidence that a provider is NOT using a PreparedStatement?

Comment: I have no evidence at all. I'm asking this question to make sure it's using prepared statements for complex, repeated queries.

Comment: since your JPA provider is open source you can then check the codebase to "make sure". One of the (many) advantages of using open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with Michele in that *generally* prepared statements are used by the underlying JPA provider/implementer. To assure that your statements are prepared and results cached (should you desire this) using standard JPA please see my response here:

[How to use PreparedStatement efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275970/how-to-use-preparedstatement-efficiently/35277013#35277013)

Comment: Unfortunately, **that's not true**. Nowhere in the JSR-338 (JPA 2.1) is stated about *preparation* or *caching* of queries or results, whether named or not. It's all up to the provider, which *generally* takes the best effort.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure how to tell JPA to (not) use a prepared statement.

You can't. It depends on the provider you use and if/how it exposes this kind of configuration.

> Is JPA automatically using prepared statments for this?

Any decent provider will use prepared statments.

> What about criteria API. My guess is that it's using dynamic sql?

Same as above. In example, Hibernate uses prepared statments even with native queries:

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2275)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
```

([credit OO7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25104891/2911357))