# Spring boot: Repository interface sql injection protection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sql-injection

I have a Repository Interface in my Spring Boot application, as you can see below.

```
@Repository
public interface CounterRepository extends JpaRepository<Counter, String> {
    Counter findByMediaName(String mediaName);
}
```

There is no implementation of this interface. It's just Spring Boot magic. I'm wondering if there is a **SQL Injection** risk for `mediaName` parameter? I'm using `Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. It will create a Criteria api query (in a right way), which will escape parameters.
It's like when you use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misconception. JPA and other ORMs relieves us from creating hand-coded SQL statements, but they won't prevent us from writing vulnerable code. [enter link description here](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-injection)

[How to How to Fix SQL Injection using the Java Persistence API (JPA)](https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-persistence-api-jpa)

[SQL injection: when a prepared statement is not enough](https://blog.jdriven.com/2017/10/sql-injection-prepared-statement-not-enough/)

[Nowhere in the JSR-338 (JPA 2.1) is stated about preparation or caching of queries or results, whether named or not. It's all up to the provider, which generally takes the best effort.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845345/how-can-i-tell-jpa-to-use-prepared-statements-or-dynamic-sql)

[Query Parameters in JPA](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter)

Comment: This is right, but he asked the interface querys. It will prevent this kind of programmer failure.
Anyway it is a useful aritcle.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for comment.